# How can i control the input field sending or not with html & javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the scenario.

There is a input field that is only `display:none`
-> lets name this 'hidden_input_field'

And there is a button to change this to `display:block`

I want to send this param if it is showed, and if it is hidden don't send this param.

But in my case, this input field is just not showing in the view, but it is existing inside the form tag, so it is always sending this parameter, whether it is hidden or not.

Can i ask a good solution about this?

Comment: I don't know you needs, but you MUST do server check anyway, even if hidden field does not exists inside form, because it's so easy to spoof form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the “name” attribute when the input is hidden and then bring it back once the field is shown.

Try this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
input#hidden_input_field {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://google.ru/" method="post">
<input id="hidden_input_field" type="text">
<button id="reveal">Reveal the field</button>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var field = document.getElementById("hidden_input_field");
var button = document.getElementById("reveal");
button.onclick = function() {
    button.style.display = "none";
    field.style.display = "block";
    field.setAttribute("name", "name_for_the_parameter");

    // This is necessary for preventing the default
    // browser’s behavior: submitting the form.
    return false;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

By default, the text field is hidden, but once the “Reveal” button is clicked, the field is displayed. While it is hidden, it doesn’t have the “name” attribute, so if you submit the form, the corresponding parameter is not included in the request. Once the field is shown, the “name” attribute is added to the element, so if you then submit the form, the corresponding parameter is included in the request.

Comment: Thanks, so the name attribute was the point, sending the parameter or not :)

Comment: Maybe toggling the `disabled` property of the `<input>` is more semantically correct.